Azure Terraform - How to avoid conflicting configuration arguments while creating NSG Rules
I am getting below error while creating azurerm_network_security_rule.
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│ "source_port_range": conflicts with source_port_ranges ..
│ "source_port_ranges": conflicts with source_port_range .. 
│ "destination_port_range": conflicts with destination_port_ranges ..
│ "destination_port_ranges": conflicts with destination_port_range ..
│ "source_address_prefix": conflicts with source_address_prefixes ..
│ "source_address_prefixes": conflicts with source_address_prefix ..
│ "destination_address_prefix": conflicts with destination_address_prefixes ..
│ "destination_address_prefixes": conflicts with destination_address_prefix ..

Code snippets:

# tfvars : 

virtual_networks = [
  {
    vnet_index          = "vnet01"
    vnet_name_suffix    = "appvnet1"
    resource_group_name = "azd-rsg-prod-net"
    location            = "EastUS"
    address_space = [
      "10.10.0.0/16"
    ]
    subnets = [
      {
        subnet_suffix = "app"
        address_space = "10.10.0.0/24"
        nsg_rules = [
          {
            rule_name                    = "SR-AllowSomePorts-Inbound"
            rule_description             = "Allow Some Ports"
            access                       = "Allow"
            direction                    = "Inbound"
            priority                     = "1001"
            protocol                     = "*"
            source_port_range            = "*"
            source_port_ranges           = []
            destination_port_range       = ""
            destination_port_ranges      = ["3389", "443", "80"]
            source_address_prefix        = "*"
            source_address_prefixes      = []
            destination_address_prefix   = "*"
            destination_address_prefixes = []
          }
        ]
      },
      # Other subnet details here..
    ]
  },
]

# Module: 

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "NgsRule" {
  for_each                     = { for nsg_rule in local.nsg_rules : nsg_rule.key_name => nsg_rule }
  name                         = each.value.rule_name
  description                  = each.value.rule_description
  access                       = each.value.access
  direction                    = each.value.direction
  priority                     = each.value.priority
  protocol                     = each.value.protocol

  # Conflicts: 
  source_port_range  = length(each.value.source_port_range) != 0 ? each.value.source_port_range : ""
  source_port_ranges = length(each.value.source_port_ranges) != 0 ? each.value.source_port_ranges : []

  destination_port_range  = length(each.value.destination_port_range) != 0 ? each.value.destination_port_range : ""
  destination_port_ranges = length(each.value.destination_port_ranges) != 0 ? each.value.destination_port_ranges : []

  source_address_prefix   = length(each.value.source_address_prefix) != 0 ? each.value.source_address_prefix : ""
  source_address_prefixes = length(each.value.source_address_prefixes) != 0 ? each.value.source_address_prefixes : []

  destination_address_prefix   = length(each.value.destination_address_prefix) != 0 ? each.value.destination_address_prefix : ""
  destination_address_prefixes = length(each.value.destination_address_prefixes) != 0 ? each.value.destination_address_prefixes : []

  resource_group_name         = each.value.resource_group_name
  network_security_group_name = each.value.nsg_name
}


How to dynamically populate singular/plural property based on the presence of singular/plural argument value?

You cant use both the singular and plural properties in the same resource block. You can always provide a singular value in the plural property as a single item in the array object.
# tfvars:
...
nsg_rules = [
          {
            rule_name                    = "SR-AllowSomePorts-Inbound"
            rule_description             = "Allow Some Ports"
            access                       = "Allow"
            direction                    = "Inbound"
            priority                     = "1001"
            protocol                     = "*"
            source_port_ranges           = ["*"]
            destination_port_ranges      = ["3389", "443", "80"]
            source_address_prefixes      = ["*"]
            destination_address_prefixes = ["*"]
          }
        ]
... 

# Module
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "NgsRule" {
...
source_port_range  = length(each.value.source_port_ranges) == 1 ? each.value.source_port_ranges[0] : null
  source_port_ranges = length(each.value.source_port_ranges) != 1 ? each.value.source_port_ranges : null
  destination_port_range  = length(each.value.destination_port_ranges) == 1 ? each.value.destination_port_ranges[0] : null
  destination_port_ranges = length(each.value.destination_port_ranges) != 1 ? each.value.destination_port_ranges : null
  source_address_prefix   = length(each.value.source_address_prefixes) == 1 ? each.value.source_address_prefixes[0] : null
  source_address_prefixes = length(each.value.source_address_prefixes) != 1 ? each.value.source_address_prefixes : null
  destination_address_prefix   = length(each.value.destination_address_prefixes) == 1 ? each.value.destination_address_prefixes[0] : null
  destination_address_prefixes = length(each.value.destination_address_prefixes) != 1 ? each.value.destination_address_prefixes : null
...
}


Great! Added code snippets. The reason for keeping the singular args was to ensure the translation between JSON view of the resource to Terraform tfvars, for the cases where changes made from portal ;). But its not going limit me, as I will write another python script to translate. Thanks !
